# creating a file using task scheduler while the windows user lock the system

Tags: windows, python-3.x, taskscheduler

I have written a bat file and writing the console output to a text file.The bat file is scheduled using the task scheduler to run at prescribed time. The bat file is executing and creating a file while the system user is not locked (I mean windows+L) but when the system is locked batch file is running but the text file is not created.Facing the similar issue with the python code also(writing the output dataframe to an excel file.Is there any suggestion on this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c03d6691-b058-4f8d-961c-e8eba25bbaed/task-scheduler-problem-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not/#answersList